# UITableView select many rows and highlight each - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there anyway to highlight each selected row and keep it highlighted until the user reclicks on the item to unhighlight it? And can the user select multiple rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, to change the hight of one cell and add a certain amount of button on this cell. You can adept it so that it triggers a number of cells, that were clicked.

I use the `int openedCellIndex` to save my clicked cell. You would use an Array of int or indexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if ( indexPath.row != openedCellIndex )
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[TRTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] 
                    autorelease];
            //cell.frame = CGRectMake (0,0, 320, 100);
        }

        id <P_E_P1Article> article = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = article.name;

        if ( self.cellBackgroundColor )
            cell.backgroundColor = self.cellBackgroundColor;

            return cell;
    }
    else {

        //get article
        id <P_E_P1Article> article = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //number of buttons
        int buttons = [article.specification count];
        int height = 50 * ceil(buttons / 2) + 50;

        //construct special cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[[TRTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                                        reuseIdentifier:@"CellBig"] 
                                 autorelease];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake (0,0, 320, 150);
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";

        //add label
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 30)];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        label.text = article.name;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell addSubview:label];
        [label release];

        if ( buttonMapper == nil )
            self.buttonMapper = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
            //NSLog (@" bla: %@", article.isFreePrice);

            //see if we have a free prized article

            //create the buttons
            NSEnumerator *enumerator = [article.specification objectEnumerator];
            id <P_E_P1ArticleSpecification> spec;
        int count = 0;

        NSArray *specs = 
        [self sortedArticleSpecifications:article];

        for ( spec in specs ) {

            //see which row and col the button is in
            int row = floor ( count / 2 );
            int col = count % 2;

            //define button position
            int left = 20 + col * 145;
            int top = 45 + row * 50;

            //create button
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(left, top, 135, 40);
            [cell addSubview:button];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:0];

            [button addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(buttonTapped:) 
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


            //remember which article the button is attached to
            buttonCounter++;

            button.tag = buttonCounter;

            [buttonMapper setValue:spec forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bla%d",buttonCounter]];

            count++;
        }


        if ( self.cellBackgroundColor )
            cell.backgroundColor = self.cellBackgroundColor;

            return cell;
    }

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( openedCellIndex == indexPath.row )
    {
        id <P_E_P1Article> article = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        int count = [article.specification count];

        int height = 50 * ceil(count / 2.) + 50;

        return height;
    }

    return 50;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self openRow:indexPath.row];
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];


}

- (void) openRow:(int) index
{
    if ( index == openedCellIndex ) return;

    int oldIndex = openedCellIndex;
    openedCellIndex = index;


    NSUInteger indexArr[] = {0, oldIndex};
    NSIndexPath *oldPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:2];

    NSUInteger indexArr2[] = {0, openedCellIndex};
    NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr2 length:2];


    //update view
    [(UITableView *)self.view beginUpdates];    
    if ( oldIndex >= 0 )
        [(UITableView *)self.view reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oldPath] 
                                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    if (openedCellIndex >=0 )
        [(UITableView *)self.view reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newPath] 
                                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [(UITableView *)self.view endUpdates];
}
```